# how to display logcat in text view in the other page?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, logging, text

i have question here.how to display log cat in text view on other page?
below shows the code for log cat.

try.java

```
                Log.e("MENU A","Total Price: RM "+price);
```

price is a double type...
what should i do to display the price in a text view on the other page?
right now i just can display the total price in log cat at the bottom of eclipse page. 
should i declare new text view?

i want to display the price in a page called testing.xml. try.java is the process page for testing.xml

help me please....

Comment: pass your variable value to redirected class using putExtra and getExtra

Comment: how is it? can u show example for me?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the developer training site regarding starting another activity.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```